# Проблема с сохранением данных с dataEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Есть код, в котором есть таймер основанный на `dataEdit`. 
Но, при нажатии на кнопку, которая проверяет прошло ли время окончания вылезает ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\PyCharm\Gui_Программы\Python\New\SL_lke2.py", line 396, in check_date
    if self._date >= dateEdit.date():
AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute '_date'
```

Вот ссылка на гугл диск где лежит логика и ui:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TRd-y_mYmHWmwXz7Z-mDB-mrtYiqutg0/view?usp=sharing,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qggoUxzg2QVrIOmXSNTFOcb2Pba8nR-I/view?usp=sharing

Как это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить строку:

```
self._date = QDate.currentDate()
```

после строки:

```
uic.loadUi("UI_lke2.1.ui", self)
```

Comment: работает. Но, при нажатии на кнопку, даже если ни одна дата не истекла все ровно вылезает уведомление об окончании какой то строчки

Comment: @АндрейАлександров если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, ОПУБЛИКУЙТЕ пример, который демонстрирует проблему и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.